# AJAX check if there is a null variable from returned data (Laravel 7)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Currently working on a Laravel 7 project and I have this code which maps the returned data from my controller to a modal. I want to check if a value is null below the 'Appointment' with the h4 tag so I don't have to append it and instead add a text which says 'No appointment yet'. Irdk if that's possible, I'm new to laravel and ajax. Thank you!

```
 $('body').on('click', '#show-schedule-btn', function () {
var schedule_id = $(this).data("id");

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/DoctorSchedule/"+schedule_id,
    data:{
        "schedule_id":schedule_id,
    },
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    const schedule_details = data;

let html = ``

schedule_details && schedule_details.map(x => {
    html += `   <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                            <input type="datepicker-show" name="date" id="date" class="form-control" value="${x.schedule_date}" readonly/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Time Start</label>
                            <input type="time" name="time_start" id="time_start" class="form-control" value="${x.time_start}" readonly/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Time End</label>
                            <input type="time" name="time_end" id="time_end" class="form-control" value="${x.time_end}" readonly/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  
                <div class="form-group">
                        <h4>Appointment</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Patient Name:</label>
                    <p>${x.first_name} ${x.last_name}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Oncology:</label>
                    <p>${x.oncology_name}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Procedure:</label>
                    <p>${x.procedure_name}</p> 
                </div>`
}) 
$("#sched-details").html(html); 
  $('#show-schedule').modal('show'); 
}
}); 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what your getting in `data` variable in ajax ?

Comment: You can check if data exists, `if(data && data !="") console.log("no data");`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes, but I don't know how to check if some of the data is NULL especially after the <h4>Appoinment</h4> I need to check if x.first_name, x.last_name... is NULL because I am getting it from another table via LEFT JOIN in my controller.

Comment: @bhucho That's for the whole data, I just need to check if x.first_name, x.last_name... is NULL because I am getting it from another table via LEFT JOIN in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, if a person is also searching for the same thing here's the answer:

```
$('body').on('click', '#show-schedule-btn', function () {
var schedule_id = $(this).data("id");

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/DoctorSchedule/"+schedule_id,
    data:{
        "schedule_id":schedule_id,
    },
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    const schedule_details = data;

    let html = ``

    const areAllReqPropsStated = (x) =>{
        return x.first_name && x.last_name && x.oncology_name && x.procedure_name;
    }

     (schedule_details || []).map(x => {
        html = `   <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                                <input type="datepicker-show" name="date" id="date" class="form-control" value="${x.schedule_date}" readonly/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Time Start</label>
                                <input type="time" name="time_start" id="time_start" class="form-control" value="${x.time_start}" readonly/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Time End</label>
                                <input type="time" name="time_end" id="time_end" class="form-control" value="${x.time_end}" readonly/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
                      
        html += areAllReqPropsStated(x)
        ? `         <hr>   
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <h4>Appointment</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Patient Name:</label>
                        <p>${x.first_name} ${x.last_name}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Oncology:</label>
                        <p>${x.oncology_name}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Procedure:</label>
                        <p>${x.procedure_name}</p> 
                    </div>`
        : `<hr>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <p>No appointment yet</p>
            </div>`;
    }) 
    $("#sched-details").html(html); 
      $('#show-schedule').modal('show'); 
    }
}); 
});
```